# asp.net pattern - domain model

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, domain-model

I am reading professional [asp.net design patterns by Scott Millet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470292784).
And I am on page 68 - reading Domain Model.

I really like the way Domain Model works. But I need simpler example to show me how it works.

Do you know any resources I can read? or even have a lab I can try and move on?
I don't need something with MVC because I am not there yet. And my domain model 
will work with different platform.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you don't need MVC because you are "not there yet".  My opinion, based on my own experience, is that a great way to build your skills would be to dual track on intro MVC while doing more reading on DDD.  Jimmy Nilsson's book, "Applying Domain-Driven Design and Patterns" is famous and comprehensive but also very approachable.  I would read that and, at the same time, step through the 29 videos at: http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-2/how-do-i/creating-a-tasklist-application-with-aspnet-mvc.

Also, you'll notice that Scott Millet thanks Rob Conery in the acknowledgements to the book.  I think you might be helped by some of Rob's free videos at TekPub.  In particular, I'm thinking of the free five part series called "Concepts" [http://tekpub.com/products/concepts] that covers DI, IoC, "Loose Design with Interfaces", "Behavior-driven Design with Specflow", and more.